# Android crash for dynamic calculation when EditText is empty

Tags: android, dynamic, crash, android-edittext

I'm working on a disk space calculator and i need to dynamically calculate some values according to user input. I have an EditText element in my application that receives numbers. I want to call my function calculate() that will calculate other values automatically when user inputs a value in the text field. Here's my code for it

```
//fps is my EditText element
this.fps.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)  
           {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        calculate();
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    });
```

My calculate() function uses the text input, converts it into float and calculates other values like bandwidth. It works fine but the problem comes when I want to delete all numbers in EditText to add another one. The moment there's nothing in the editText it gives an exception. Which I understand, it's because there's nothing to convert into float so parsing exception etc. 
I tried putting a default value

```
if(fps.getText().length==0)
    fps.setText("1");
```

But it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try to surround your `calculate()` with try/catch block and catch the exception thrown..

```
try { 
  calculate();
} catch {NumberFormatException nfe) { //or whatever exception you get
      //do some handling if you need to
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.fps.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         if(!s.toString().trim().equals(""))
             calculate();
         else
             //do nothing here or show error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution I tried it and it works +1 for that but as I can't accept more than one answers I think I'll use the try catch block solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call your calculate() in onTextChanged() when at least single charcter is there in your edittext like this.

```
if(fps.getText.length>0){
calculate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your operation in `afterTextChanged`